# Has the patent been issued

Tags: wo2010122232a1

In reference to the patent: [WO2010122232A1](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2010122232A1)

has this been issued or was just an application filed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Lens.org patent family feature](https://www.lens.org/lens/patent/WO_2010_122232_A1/family) to explore the status of this application in diverse jurisdictions:  It shows that it is still at application status in the US and in WO (which does not grant patents of course).  However there is a Finnish document whose status is unclear to me.

Lens.org patent family facility is open, free and secure, and allows this type of question to be posed by anyone for any patent document.  Follow up with particular statutory holdings (eg. Finnish or US Patent Offices) should be considered once you have the information in hand.

Answer (score 0):

The application died in the examination procedures:
https://register.epo.org/application?number=EP10766706&lng=en&tab=main
It was deemed withdrawn in European procedure, I think it never really entered the regional phase there. 
In US it was abandoned. You need to go to "patent family" on the left and then check the US application.
Register Plus quite often gives a complete overview of the developement of WO (PCT) fillings.